# Recursive CTE to split rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a CTE that returns a set of item IDs and quantities. I'm trying to use another CTE to split each row into multiple rows based on a defined container size. For example, if the container size is specified as 20 and the row quantity is 49, I'd like to split it into 2 rows of with quantity 20 and one row of 9.

Below is where I'm finally stuck. Is a recursive CTE the wrong choice for this scenario? Any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @ContainerSize int = 20;

WITH ItemDetails (ItemID, Qty) AS (
    -- Query that returns data like below
    SELECT 29, 49
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 33, 64
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 38, 32
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 41, 54
),
ItemDetailsSplit(n, ItemID, Qty) AS (
    SELECT  
        0,
        ItemID,
        Qty
    FROM ItemDetails
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        n + 1,
        ItemID,
        CASE WHEN Qty < (@ContainerSize * (n + 1))
            THEN Qty
            ELSE Qty - (@ContainerSize * (n + 1))
        END AS [Qty]        
    FROM ItemDetailsSplit   
    WHERE ( Qty > (@ContainerSize * n) )
)
SELECT * 
FROM ItemDetailsSplit
ORDER BY ItemID, Qty DESC;
```

Comment: You probably don't need a recursive CTE here, tag your specific database eg, MySql, Postgres, SQL Server etc...

Comment: Updated with SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your specific RDBMS I have a solution that works with SQL Server, it's easily convertable to any database platform.

This uses a *numbers table* - here another CTE but in production you'd have a permanent table.

```
declare @ContainerSize int = 20;
with numbers (n) as (
    select top(100) Row_Number() over(order by(select null)) from master.dbo.spt_values
), ItemDetails (ItemID, Qty) as (
    -- Query that returns data like below
    select 29, 49
    union all
    select 33, 64
    union all
    select 38, 32
    union all
    select 41, 54
)
select ItemID, Iif(n <= Qty / @ContainerSize, @ContainerSize, Qty % @ContainerSize) Qty
from ItemDetails d
cross apply numbers n
where n <= (Qty / @ContainerSize) + Iif(Qty % @ContainerSize = 0, 0, 1)
order by ItemID, Qty
```

See [working DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ae13a56977b21bd39966add6b1250f2)

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks! Only change I had to make was casting for the modulo operator, CAST(CAST(Qty AS decimal(38,19)) % @ContainerSize AS float), since my true values are floats and not ints like in my example. Not pretty, but works for now.

Comment: One other change I'd share, since the master.dbo.spt_values table is an undocumented table I can't trust that it will always be there so changed the numbers query to:

WITH numbers (n) AS (
     SELECT 1 AS n
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n + 1 FROM numbers WHERE n + 1 <= 100
    ),

Comment: @scumdogg Yes this was purely for a quick example, a recursive CTE also works of course and is fine for smallish data sets, sometimes though a permanent numbers table makes sense for ranges of 1000s or millions of rows and if oyu have a permanent numbers table it just makes sense to use it.